# How to force new visible height to a div and show the rest with scrollbar functionality?

Tags: css, html, overflow

I have a `<div id='x' />` with height 300px

and inside of it I want to put a `<div id='y' />` of height 600px

Now when I do that, the Y div appears in its full height where as I want it to appear up to 300px (in height) and add a Y-axis scrollbar functionality for the rest to appear

I am adding `overflow-y:visible` to my Y div but I don't get the result I want, nothing changes

I'm fairly new to web development and I get pretty confused when it comes to nested divs and forcing heights, adding scrollbars.. etc

In this specific case, how exactly can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Note: `<div>` can't be self closed, whether you have content inside it or not it should always have an ending tag `<div></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not going to work the way you think it will. If you use the other answers here you'll get two scroll bars, one for x and one for y. If you set x to overflow:hidden, x remains the right size but the scroll bar of y goes beyond the bottom of x.

What you want to do is set both divs to the same size (or y smaller than x) and let the overflow do the work. There is no point in making y bigger if it is going to scroll anyway.

```
#x{max-height:100px;height:100px;overflow:hidden;}
#y{height:100px;overflow-y:scroll;}​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/V9THr/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try overflow: auto; on div with id x

Comment: That would result in two scroll bars.

Comment: I've never crossed that problem. Any specific browser?

Comment: >.< nvm my mistake I was combining that with his overflow on y. You're right that works too. Although if he wants other content in x to remain in place it won't work

Comment: Yeah, but I assumed that all content in x should be scrollable. I guess it all comes down to interpretation :)

Comment: Yup, I assumed he wanted x static, otherwise why even bother with y? lol

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the overflow do this

```
#x {overflow: auto};
```

if you want to make a scrollbar inside do this

```
#x {overflow: scroll};
```

Answer (score 1):

That's very simple. You just have to apply `overflow:scroll;` to the container for the Y-axis scrollbars to appear. Check this fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/DeepakKamat/vBFJG/3/

Adding `overflow:visible;` to #y `<div>` will do nothing if you want have an element overflows the #y element.